# SingularValueDecomposition

Tags: java, apache-modules

Хочу испробовать из библиотеки apache commons math svd алгоритм, если не вдаваться в подробности это разложение матрицы на 3 матрицы U V S. Я создал пробник для матрицы 3 на 3, вот [ссылка на документацию](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/SingularValueDecomposition.html).

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.RealMatrix;
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.SingularValueDecomposition;

public class matrics {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    public RealMatrix getV(int[][] a) {
        int[][] A = new int[3][3];
        A[0][0] = 1;
        A[0][1] = 2;
        A[0][2] = 3;
        A[1][0] = 2;
        A[1][1] = 4;
        A[1][2] = 6;
        A[2][0] = 1;
        A[2][1] = 3;
        A[2][2] = 3;
    }
}
```

Что сделать дальше как вызвать то что я хочу??

Comment: Честно говоря у вас этот метод немного не относится к тому, что вы описали в вопросе.Потому, что у вас сейчас все сводится к `return A`; а в методе `main` использование матрицы.... но...метод `getV` вообще-то связан с классом `SingularValueDecomposition` и нужно реализовывать через него..... `final Array2DRowRealMatrix m = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(matrix); final SingularValueDecompositionImpl svd = new SingularValueDecompositionImpl( m ); final RealMatrix v = svd.getV();`, где `matrix` - ваша матрица

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из документации видно, что вам необходимо сконструировать утилиту SingularValueDecomposition и подать ей на вход RealMatrix с вашими значениями.

Так как у Array2DRowRealMatrix есть только конструктор от матрицы double, то я позволил себе слегка изменить ваш код:

```
    double[][] matrix = new double[3][3];

    matrix[0][0] = 1;
    matrix[0][1] = 2;
    matrix[0][2] = 3;
    matrix[1][0] = 2;
    matrix[1][1] = 4;
    matrix[1][2] = 6;
    matrix[2][0] = 1;
    matrix[2][1] = 3;
    matrix[2][2] = 3;

    RealMatrix rm = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(matrix);
    SingularValueDecomposition dec = new SingularValueDecomposition(rm);

    System.out.println("U = " + dec.getU());
    System.out.println("V = " + dec.getV());
    System.out.println("S = " + dec.getS());
```

stdout:

> U = Array2DRowRealMatrix{{0.3975434584,-0.2048394461,0.894427191},{0.7950869169,-0.4096788921,-0.4472135955},{0.4580349259,0.8889341971,-0.0}}
>
> V = Array2DRowRealMatrix{{0.260076626,-0.1798892676,0.9486832981},{0.5688598124,0.8224345043,0.0},{0.780229878,-0.5396678029,-0.316227766}}
>
> S = Array2DRowRealMatrix{{9.4039678063,0.0,0.0},{0.0,0.7519238642,0.0},{0.0,0.0,0.0}}